# JDK 7 in Netbeans for OS X Lion

Tags: java, macos, netbeans, java-7

I am in the process of learning Java and the book I am using has code that requires Java 7. I downloaded the JDK7 developer preview from Google Code so I could add it as a Platform in Netbeans, when I select the 1.7.jdk, file the `Next` button turns grey for some reason as you can see in the image below:
[image: Greyed out "Next" button]

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: What book are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow these [instructions](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/javase-jdk7.html) on how to setup Netbean 7 for JDK7.

Comment: Ah! I forgot to go to the right file inside the JDK.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

make sure you press SOURCES then click add platform, the default selection is CLASSES.